# Scale Weight -> NodeJS via TCP Socket to JSON for Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, sockets

Trying (semi successfully) to pull weight from TCP socket. I'd like to then output the data to JSON string so I could then wrap it in some angular. You can see in the console I'm receiving the weight, I'll eventually strip out the start and end of text items so the the output would look something like:

{ "scaleA": '   43636LG ',"scaleB" etc......}

**weightclient.js**

```
'use strict'

var net = require('net');
var HOST = '192.168.1.17';
var PORT = 1337;
var client = new net.Socket(); 

var weight = function(){
    var weights = {};
    client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
        console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
        client.on('data', function(data) {
            // console.log('DATA: ' + data);
            weights.scaleA = data.toString();
            console.log(weights);
            client.destroy();
        });
        client.on('close', function() {
            console.log('Connection closed');
        });
    });
    return {
      weights  
    };
}();
console.log(weight);
module.exports = weight;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var net = require('net');
var getweight = require('../weightclient.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


router.get('/weight', function(req, res) {
    getweight.weight(function(err, data){
      console.log(data);  
    });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

**Console (output):**

```
 node bin/www
{ weights: {} }
CONNECTED TO: 192.168.1.17:1337
{ scaleA: '\u0002   43636LG \r\n' }
Connection closed
GET /weight 500 2973.083 ms - 1131
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 25.835 ms - -
```

**Web Output:**

```
getweight.weight is not a function

TypeError: getweight.weight is not a function
    at /home/pi/socketio-test/routes/index.js:13:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/home/pi/socketio-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

Thoughts suggestions .. still learning node and js, any pointers or reference marital is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something key, your `return { weights };` is invalid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have (I love english):

1. Server which resposes with packet weight. (ok)
2. Client that outputs everyting urgent. (ok)

On client define:

```
var arr = []
```

And code:

```
when response from server       arrive{
arr.push([data.name,data.weight])}
```

Then you can code other things.
Hope I understood your question right.

My way will save you much time debugging.

The error btw is in required file, so I cant help at all, the weight is not defined as function, or its defined in private way.